# API key not allowed when using Weather service

Tags: ibm-cloud, weather

I built a simple Node.js app that worked with the Weather service. It worked fine for a while, but about 24 hours ago started returning this error:

`{"metadata":{"version":"1","transaction_id":"1:1362317376","status_code":401},"success":false,"errors":[{"error":{"code":"AGW-0210","message":"Api not allowed for this api key."}}]}`

I've double checked my authentication information and it is correct.

Comment: May be there is a limitation for this Weather Service. Check with the support, may be they have a solution for your issue $$

Comment: The error should - I would expect - state that I went over the limit. This error seems to be something else.

Comment: Can you check with the support ?

Answer (score 0):

The 401 response indicates authentication failed. But it may also have been the service unavailable or a plan limit reached. Are you still seeing this problem? Is it intermittent? or continuously failing?

There is a brief explanation of the throttling of the API when it hits the limits of the plan that you selected. See [here](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/Weather/index.html), in the bottom paragraph of the first section.

You can check the status of the Bluemix platform [here](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#status).

Comment: Well, I'm thinking it was rate limiting. Eventually it worked again. However the error *really* needs to be updated.

Comment: I have the same error using the poster app to verify the call.
The service worked some weeks before, I used whisk and I did this video https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLUte4WEyMEjX8jfsXXy-IJ8ApwmFrmXm6 it worked fine.

But now I get this error:
{"metadata": { "version": "1", "transaction_id":"1:1048282893","status_code": 401},"success": false,"errors": [ {"error": { "code": "AGW-0210","message": "Api not allowed for this api key."}} ]}

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for me, just delete the old service and create a new one.
This works fine for me.